# How to add multiple divider component in a react navigation drawer

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-navigation-drawer

I have a drawer navigation, what I wanted to happen is add divider separating the drawer icon and texts, but I get an error instead

Error is: A navigator can only contain screen components...

Here is my approach:

```
function DrawerNav(): React$Element<{}> {
  return (
    <Drawer.Navigator
      drawerStyle={styles.drawerStyle}
      drawerContentOptions={{
        activeTintColor: 'white',
        inactiveTintColor: 'white',
        activeBackgroundColor: '#163E69',
        inactiveBackgroundColor: '#02152B'
      }}>

      <Drawer.Screen
        name="Dashboard"
        component={Dashboard}
        options={{
          drawerIcon: () => (
            <Image source = {"assets/icons/dashboard.png"} />
          ),
        }}
      />

     <DrawerDivider label="Account" />    // This is my divider component

     <Drawer.Screen
        name="Profile"
        component={Profile}
        options={{
          drawerIcon: () => (
            <Image source={'assets/icons/profile.png'} />
          ),
        }}
      />

    <DrawerDivider label="Actions" />   // also my divider component

    <Drawer.Screen
        name="Settings"
        component={Settings}
        options={{
          drawerIcon: () => (
            <Image source={'assets/icons/settings.png'} />
          ),
        }}
      />

    <DrawerDivider label="Actions" />   // also my divider component

    <Drawer.Screen
        name="Logout"
        component={Logout}
        options={{
          drawerIcon: () => (
            <Image source={'assets/icons/logout.png'} />
          ),
        }}
      />

   </Drawer.Navigator>
  );
}
```

Any suggestions/help are appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

this how I implemented it in my project , you need to create a custom `drawerContent` component  , `drawerContent` gives incredible amount of flexibility you can literally create what ever you want with it .

Navigator :

```
  import DrawerContent from './DrawerContent'
  import { createDrawerNavigator } from '@react-navigation/drawer';
  const Navigator =({authenticated,userType})=>{
      const Drawer = createDrawerNavigator();
      return <Drawer.Navigator 
             screenOptions={{headerShown:false}} 
             initialRouteName="INTIALROUTE"
             drawerContent={props => <DrawerContent {...props} />}
              >
             <Drawer.Screen name="route1"  component={Screen1} />
             <Drawer.Screen name="route1" component={Screen2} />
      </Drawer.Navigator>
 }
```

the custom `drawerContent` component  :

```
import React from 'react'
import {StyleSheet,View,Text,TouchableOpacity} from 'react-native' 
import {DrawerContentScrollView,DrawerItem} from '@react-navigation/drawer';


const DrawerContent=(props)=> {
    const {navigation}=props
  
 
    const naviagetToRoute=(e)=>{
         navigation.navigate(route)
    }
 
    //here you can return diffrent drawerContent based on auth state for example
    if(isAuthenticated){
    //isAuthenticated can be passed through props using redux's connect or context api 
     return  <View style={{flex:1}}>
            <DrawerContentScrollView {...props}>
                <TouchableOpacity  onPress={naviagetToRoute}>
                     <View style={styles.drawerItem}> 
                         <Image source = {"assets/icons/logout.png"} /> 
                        <Text style={{color:colors.BLACK}} >Logout</Text>
                       </View>
                  </TouchableOpacity>
            </DrawerContentScrollView>
        </View>   
    }

    return (
        <View style={{flex:1}}>
            <DrawerContentScrollView {...props}>
                <TouchableOpacity  onPress={naviagetToRoute}>
                     <View style={styles.drawerItem}> 
                         <Image source = {"assets/icons/dashboard.png"} />
                        <Text style={{color:colors.BLACK}} >DashBoard</Text>
                       </View>
                  </TouchableOpacity>
            </DrawerContentScrollView>
        </View>
    )

}

export default DrawerContent

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    drawerItem: {
        display :'flex',
        flexDirection:'row',
        alignItems:'center',
        justifyContent:"space-between",
        padding:16,
        elevation:12,
        backgroundColor:'#fff',
        borderRadius:12,
        marginBottom:16,
        flex:1
    }
  });
```

Comment: So where exactly is the divider?

Comment: its easy to add a divider to my implementation u can do somthing like : 
```<View style={{flex:1}}>
            <DrawerContentScrollView {...props}>
               ...
            </DrawerContentScrollView>
             <Divider /> 
     <Divider title ="some title" /> 
     <DrawerContentScrollView {...props}>
               ...
            </DrawerContentScrollView>
     <Divider title ="some title" /> 
     <DrawerContentScrollView {...props}>
               ...
            </DrawerContentScrollView>
        </View>
```

Comment: Do I create the Divider component myself or it is imported from `@react-navigation`

Comment: @Youzef yeah create it your self its a simple element treat it as if you were building using html because this is a custom drawer  .